# Linux SERVER swap memory

Tags: linux, memory, swap

I have a linux server. It is running java process namely kafka. I set vm.swapiness = 10. But I see the swap capacity keeps increasing, There is a lot of free memory space.  Can someone explain to me the root cause of this. My app still run fine but the constantly increase swap is causing some warning.

```
[root@micro-kafka01 sysdba]# top -b -n1 -o RES
top - 13:39:21 up 68 days, 21:42,  1 user,  load average: 5.03, 4.71, 4.88
Tasks: 266 total,   2 running, 264 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 56.2 us,  9.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 31.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  2.8 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 49293772 total,   289180 free, 32103672 used, 16900920 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  8392700 total,   964544 free,  7428156 used. 16106396 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 6586 microka+  20   0  204.3g  26.9g  57352 S 517.6 57.2 364517:50 java
 8165 microka+  20   0   10.5g 763088   2828 S   0.0  1.5  22494:50 kafka_exporter
 6376 microka+  20   0 8952432 527588   5916 S   0.0  1.1 456:46.74 java
 3688 oracle    20   0 5944276 417544   5976 S   0.0  0.8 180:31.61 java
 1817 root      20   0 3398916 272708  65504 S   0.0  0.6   1627:26 lightagent
 2292 root      20   0  602088 271352   5708 S   0.0  0.6   1038:31 splunkd
25419 root      20   0  711476 223912   4916 S   0.0  0.5   5:37.05 salt-minion
 2003 root      20   0 3222560  89984  77732 S   0.0  0.2  68:35.68 cvd
 1784 root      20   0 1831988  75056  11388 S   0.0  0.2 698:11.24 klnagent
 2529 root      20   0  778156  31716   9168 R   5.9  0.1   2283:11 BESClient
 1451 root      20   0  586428  21216   5748 S   0.0  0.0   9:05.52 tuned
 8138 microka+  20   0  116720  13596   1736 S   0.0  0.0  27:17.37 node_exporter
 1069 polkitd   20   0  614428  10880   4396 S   0.0  0.0   2:13.58 polkitd
 2314 root      20   0  130944   9440    640 S   0.0  0.0   2:18.50 splunkd
 2022 root      20   0 1217164   9004   7700 S   0.0  0.0  17:12.01 ClMgrS
 1456 root      20   0  801808   8872   5452 S   0.0  0.0   8:14.39 rsyslogd

[root@micro-kafka01 sysdba]# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            47G         30G        291M        601M         16G         15G
Swap:          8.0G        7.1G        941M
```

Comment: The constantly increasing swap usage is indicative of an application that is using more and more virtual memory. Also see [What is the Recommended RAM size for kafka brokers…](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53860550/2344631)

Comment: @ChrisDavies virtual memory shouldn't lead to swap, only real physical memory (RSS / Page cache) AFAIK. My guess would be that kafka is running under container/cgroup that limits it's `memory.limit_in_bytes`, so the process in the cgroup will start swapping out when they reach the limit even if there's still free total RAM on the system.

Comment: @aviro allocating virtual memory? Sure, this won't touch swap. But if you use it then eventually you're going to exceed either physical or containerised limits and it's going to need to be paged to swap. So if swap usage is climbing then it's using more and more virtual memory

Comment: @ChrisDavies oh, I missunderstood you. Yeah, you're right.

Comment: @ChrisDavies Kafka is running on bare server. I don't run kafka in container

Comment: You may want to add some data to that question, e.g. the output of: `free -m`, `top -b -n1 -o RES` as **TEXT** in a code-field ...

Comment: @tink I added the metric that you need to trace on post

Comment: @ChrisDavies I added the some metric to post. What are the metrics that you want to show?

Comment: I don't know enough about kafka to make a decent guess, but it seems that your java & kafka are eating all the ram; how much tweaking to the settings and/or the startup scripts you need to do I can't tell... maybe your config is meant for a machine with 64 GB, but it certainly doesn't have enough for what you're currently trying to run.

Comment: @tink, I think that you are misunderstanding the problem  i want to ask. I want to clear why os use swap while memory still is free.

Comment: I changed vm.swapiness= 10. Why is os still keep using swap

Comment: Swap is being used for pages that aren't being used. This allows the system to use more of its physical memory for buffer cache. Have you considered either removing swap entirely or setting swappiness=0?

Comment: You've got 48GB of RAM and your JAVA application has already consumed 27GB and 5GB for other applications which is quite a lot given your entire RAM.

On top of that you've got roughly 17GB of data cached, and the amount of free RAM is close to zero.

Given those two prepositions, the kernel is starting to use SWAP based on its heuristics. You can always disable SWAP completely if you don't like it. I've not used SWAP since 2000. At my work we have 1 out of several hundred servers which uses SWAP and it's a very cheap VPS for which we don't want to pay at all.

Comment: If the cache is heavily used and/or there are spikes of dirty cache (i.e., spikes of low available memory), then app data will get pushed out to swap and remain there until needed ... so the static numbers may not tell the story. Also, I'd try to associate the used swap to the processes to ensure there is not some nefarious factor at play.  I like [pmemstat](https://pypi.org/project/pmemstat/) for more complete memory analysis. If you wish, share its output, too.